# error: invalid use of void expression for an int type function

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, subset

I am trying to solve a question in which we have to find all those sub sets of an array/vector which sums up to be equal to a user defined number.
I decided to solve it recursively using vectors. Here is the code -

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<int> v1{1,2,3};
int n = v1.size();
int sum = 4;

int subset(vector<int> cur, int i);

int main() {
    vector <int> v;
    cout<<subset(v,0);
    return 0;
}

int subset(vector<int> cur, int i = 0){
    
    if(i == n && accumulate(cur.begin(), cur.end(), 0) == sum)
        return 1;
    else if(i == n && accumulate(cur.begin(), cur.end(), 0) != sum)
        return 0; 
    return (subset(cur, i+1) + subset(cur.push_back(v1[i]), i+1));      
}
```

I am getting an error 'invalid use of void expression' even though subset function is int type and it is returning an integer value. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `push_back` returns `void`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in line `return (subset(cur, i+1) + subset(cur.push_back(v1[i]), i+1));`

`cur.push_back` has declaration - `void push_back (const value_type& val);`

It returns void.